# Flutter Auth on iOS hangs when retrieving token with code exchange

Tags: ios, flutter, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I have the following code in flutter trying to retrieve an oauth2 token via auth code with PKCE flow:

```dart
final FlutterAppAuth appAuth = FlutterAppAuth();

final request = AuthorizationTokenRequest(
    B2C_CLIENT_ID,
    B2C_REDIRECT_URI,
    discoveryUrl: 'https://$B2C_DOMAIN/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
    // promptValues: ['login']
);

final AuthorizationTokenResponse result =
    await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(request);
```

When this code is run in iOS, the browser opens and I can see it tries to load the signin page, but then immediately closes. No exceptions are thrown or anything. The code basically hangs at `appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode` almost like it doesn't know that the browser has closed.

I am not sure what could be causing this.

The code correctly determines the url for showing credentials using the `discoveryUrl` (i.e. it makes the http request first using the `discoveryUrl`) but not sure why it basically hangs after.

I am using azureb2c for authentication here.

**Edit**

Ok turns out this is a problem with using azure b2c in particular as tried it with a different identity provider and works fine.

I managed to locate the issue and fix it now a login page shows in the browser. After entering credentials, browser closes, but code still hangs on `appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(request);` and does not proceed.

Also found existing issue. on github: https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_appauth/issues/182

Comment: Why don't you just use Firebase for authentication? It's a lot easier.

Comment: Because I simply just want to authenticate at this moment ;)

Comment: You should explain how you have configured federation of AAD B2C with Auth0. Your problem sounds like Auth0 makes a request to AAD B2Cs /token endpoint and gets an error back whilst redeeming the auth code. Since Auth0 web server is making this request to AAD B2C, you need to check *Auth0* logs, or AAD B2C Sign In Logs.

Comment: I do apologise that was a bad copypaste. I'm not using auth0. Amended.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this following the below answer on the Github repository of the `flutter_appauth` plugin.

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_appauth/issues/182#issuecomment-840707729

Eventually, all I had to do was to add a trailing slash to the redirect url parameter in `AuthorizationTokenRequest`.
(It looks like Azure AD appends on a trailing slash to the redirect url which causes the validation in AppAuth to fail).

My app worked correctly with the slash both on Android and iOS.

P.S. If this doesn't work for someone, try to adjust the redirect url in your App Registration as suggested in the respective thread https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_appauth/issues/223.

Comment: Adding the trailing slash worked for my application, cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is related to the call to **resumeExternalUserAgentFlow**, so here is a plan of action for you:

1. Follow the steps in my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/ios-setup/) to get the AppAuth Swift + Carthage sample working - which also uses a Private URI Scheme. Use my online configuration details as specified in the blog post and you should have a working solution. I have just verified that my instructions still work.
2. Update the same sample to use your Azure AD configuration and see if it  still works. If so then there is nothing wrong with AppAuth and the problem is in the Flutter layer.
3. If the Swift sample fails when you update to Azure AD configuration, add some print messages for the URL being supplied to resumeExternalUserAgentFlow in the AppDelegate class, and see if this is different to the original redirect URI. If the redirect URIs are different, reset to the original value and hopefully that will resolve things.

Comment: Using a private/native scheme. I left a comment in the github issue. Might be an issue with the way azure is returning the redirect uri. The fork that has been made solves the problem, but of course is not the ideal solution (due to what was done in the fork).

Comment: OK - I updated my answer above - it is worth looking at the AppAuth sample and seeing if the problems occur there. As you say I would aim to avoid unofficial forks.